# Axioms in protege: one of the windows shows missing "plugin"

Tags: protege

I have been trying to search what plugin might be missing in protege without success. Currently, as you can see in the figure, when I click on the "Axioms" tab I get a "missing plugin". As I was not sure what could be missing, I installed all the plugins, besides a couple of reasoners.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: What version of Protege are you using?

Comment: If you don't have a console output, start Protege from a command line (run.sh or run.bat commands in the Protege folder), so error messages should be shown there during startup and will be available for you to copy and paste here. The missing plugin is very likely to be mentioned there.

Comment: I am using protege 5.5.0. I did check the console output (I am launching in windows using run.bat) and I cannot see anything strange. Only possible thing is a Warning "Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002"